# Modify a Set-Cookie header with nginx reverse proxy by adding ";SameSite=None"

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm having a hard time on this...
My server sets multiple cookies and wants to rewrite one of them by appending ";SameSite=None" to it. Prefer not to append this to all Set-Cookie headers.

I want to rewrite this set cookie header
`Set-Cookie: my-cookie=xyz; Path=/; ...;Secure; HttpOnly`
to
`Set-Cookie: my-cookie=xyz; Path=/; ...;Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None`.

I'm using nginx 1.21.4. Trying several with `ngx_http_map_module` but with no success.